# how can I pass the value of a select with disabled in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I am using a select disabled to pass the value to an input but I can't find the way before without the disabled I used this:

```
 private subscribeToForm = () => {
    this.form.get('idLinea').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value)
      this.handleIdLineaChange(value);    
    });   }
```

and here I used the value to show it in the input

```
private handleIdLineaChange = (value) => {
    if (value) {
      const idTipoLinea = this.form.get('idLinea').value;
      console.log(idTipoLinea)
      const fechaEvento = this.form.get('fechaEvento').value;

      let fecha = new Date(fechaEvento);

      this.presupuestoService.getPresupuesto(idTipoLinea, fecha.getFullYear()).subscribe((resp) => {
        const pto = resp.data[0];
        this.form.patchValue({
          presupuestoAsignadoLinea: pto.ptoAsignado,
          presupuestoUsado: pto.ptoUsado,
          presupuestoDisponible: pto.ptoDisponible
        });
      }, () => {
        this.toastService.warning(MESSAGES.NO_EXISTE_PRESUPUESTO);
      });
    } else {
      this.form.patchValue({
        presupuestoAsignadoLinea: null,
        presupuestoUsado: null,
        presupuestoDisponible: null
      });
    }
  }
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <lib-form-control isRequired
                      label="Línea"
                      variant="select"
                      placeholder
                      controlName="idLinea"
                      bindValue="idParam"
                      bindLabel="valor"
                      [formGroupParent]="form"
                      [options]="state.comboLists.linea.list"
                      [disabled]="true"
                      >
    </lib-form-control>   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: to get a value of a formControl  with `formControlName="idLinea"` disabled you can **not** use `form.value.idLinea`, use `form.getRawValue().idLinea`, see https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue

Comment: @Eliseo Hello and how can I pass the value parameter to the handleIdLineaChange function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.form.get('idLinea').value should work anycase

I think that your problem is that the valueChanges not executed. I think you need use`startWith` rxjs/operator in valueChanges to execute the change at first

```
this.form
  .get('idLinea')
  .valueChanges.pipe(
           startWith(this.form.get('idLinea').value))
  .subscribe(value=> {
    this.handleIdLineaChange(value);    
  });
```

See this [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bfyxxe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)